# Looking for International Platforms for Self-Publishing Technical Books

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, resources, science

I am a technical book author looking to sell my work internationally. I have been publishing my technical books on a platform called ['Zenn'](https://zenn.dev/books/explore) in Japan, and I am wondering if there are similar services available for international audiences.
The Leanpub site is close to what I have in mind, but I am looking for a site with a little more natural science content.

Specifically, I am looking for platforms that:

- Allow individuals to publish and sell their own technical books.
- The content is weather data analysis and bioinformatics.
- Operate by taking a commission from the sales.
- Mainly focus on digital publications.

If anyone is aware of such platforms, could you please share the information?